# Openstack sdk not working in XNA 4.0 Project

Tags: rackspace-cloud, rackspace

I am trying to use rackspace cloud service with my xna 4.0 game, but its sdk is not working. I manage to work with sdk in wpf application but don't know what is issue with xna

following is error what i a getting:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024894
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'SimpleRESTServices, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=rack
  FileName=SimpleRESTServices, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = SIMFORM\Shivam.Singh
LOG: DisplayName = SimpleRESTServices, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Shivam.Singh/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/bin/x86/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## Calling assembly : openstacknet, Version=1.2.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Shivam.Singh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\bin\x86\Debug\WindowsGame1.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shivam.Singh/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/bin/x86/Debug/SimpleRESTServices.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shivam.Singh/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/bin/x86/Debug/SimpleRESTServices/SimpleRESTServices.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shivam.Singh/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/bin/x86/Debug/SimpleRESTServices.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shivam.Singh/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/WindowsGame1/bin/x86/Debug/SimpleRESTServices/SimpleRESTServices.EXE.

StackTrace:
       at rack.Class1.showMEssage()
       at WindowsGame1.Game1.Initialize() in C:\Users\Shivam.Singh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\Game1.cs:line 38
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
       at WindowsGame1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Shivam.Singh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\Program.cs:line 15
  InnerException:

Answer (score 0):

We're working on correcting this for the next release. The solution until then is to manually install version 1.2.0.0 the SimpleRESTServices package from NuGet prior to installing the openstack.net SDK. If you already have other versions of these packages installed, you will need to uninstall them first.